# Compose Runtime can't find my custom theme

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to play around with `Jetpack Compose` and got stuck in the first activiity itself.

My App crashes on launch with below exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.chanse.locals.cerve.dev, PID: 19105
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method ChanseTheme(ZLkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;II)V in class Lio/chanse/locals/commonui/theme/ChanseThemeKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.chanse.locals.commonui.theme.ChanseThemeKt' appears in /data/app/io.chanse.locals.cerve.dev-E-UJEroB15OQtmBe0WnvGw==/base.apk!classes5.dex)
    at io.chanse.locals.cerve.location.LocationActivity.Screen(LocationActivity.kt:45)
    at io.chanse.locals.cerve.location.LocationActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(LocationActivity.kt:39)
    at io.chanse.locals.cerve.location.LocationActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(LocationActivity.kt:38)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:46)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:333)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:179)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:178)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:46)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:46)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:46)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:46)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3418)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2600)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:348)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:693)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:304)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:603)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:667)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21304)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4239)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4246)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4246)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4246)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2571)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2225)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9126)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:999)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:732)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8173)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Here is my Activity code (`:app` module):

```
class LocationActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Screen()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Screen() {
        ChanseTheme {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                PinCodeField()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun PinCodeField() {
        var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.ask_pincode)) },
            leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.LocationOn, null) },
            trailingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowForward, null) },
            singleLine = true,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
    }
}
```

Here is my Theme present in `ChanseTheme.kt` (`:commonui` module)

```
@Composable
fun ChanseTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColors else LightColors,
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

And my colors present in `ChanseColors.kt` (`:commonui` module)

```
val DarkColors = darkColors(
    primary = Purple200,
    primaryVariant = Purple600,
    secondary = Green200,
    secondaryVariant = Green500,
    background = Black900,
    surface = Black800,
    error = Red200,
    onPrimary = Black900,
    onSecondary = Black900,
    onBackground = White50,
    onSurface = White50,
    onError = Black900
)

val LightColors = lightColors(
    primary = Purple500,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Green200,
    secondaryVariant = Green500,
    background = White50,
    surface = White50,
    error = Red600,
    onPrimary = White50,
    onSecondary = Black900,
    onBackground = Black900,
    onSurface = Black900,
    onError = White50
)
```

FYI: Here is the dependecies: (`:buildSrc` module)

```
object Activity {
    const val activityCompose = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha04"
}

object Compose {
    const val version = "1.0.0-beta02"

    const val runtime = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$version"
    const val runtimeLivedata = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$version"
    const val material = "androidx.compose.material:material:$version"
    const val icon = "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$version"
    const val iconX = "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$version"
    const val foundation = "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$version"
    const val layout = "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$version"
    const val ui = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$version"
    const val tooling = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$version"
    const val animation = "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$version"
    const val uiTest = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$version"
}

object Lifecycle {
    const val viewModelCompose = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"
}
```

The above dependencies are present in `:commonui` module as `api` and the entire module is used as dependency in `:app` module.

What could go wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

This issue was caused because your `:commonui` doesn't configure `build.gradle` file in an appropriate for jetpack compose way:

```
android {
   
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion = kotlin_version
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = compose_version
    }
   
    
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
}
```

Try to configure `:commonui` and all traversal modules in this way and it should work.

> Traversal modules:
>
> for example you have the next module graph -> `:commonui`-> A ->
> `module_which_has_a_problem` In this situation, you have to configure
> module `A` in the same way

Comment: Thank you @Pavlo Zoria, this was the issue for me.

Comment: I missed the `kotlinCompilerVersion = kotlin_version` line

Answer (score 2):

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion = kotlin_version
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = compose_version
}
```

These two blocks are needed in each modules using compose, even when you are importing the compose dependencies in a common module.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug. I get the same error when I run Previews on a real device sometimes. So I suggest :

- Making sure you're running the Activity and not the Preview (check the selected run configuration next to the run button)
- Try to run on the emulator

Compose tooling is quite unstable at the moment, in my experience. Be prepared to do things like invalidate cache, alternate compose versions to force some kind of reset, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with below changes:

Moved my `ChanseTheme.kt` and `ChanseColors.kt` files from `:commonui` module to `:app` module and it started working.

But I am not sure, why it doesn't work if those two files were present in my `:commonui` module.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is because you're using the multiplatform plugin. If your `:commonui` module was pure android ("kotlin-android" instead of "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform") it would run without crashes.

In order to fix this and keep using multiplatform, simply add this plugin on your module: `id("org.jetbrains.compose").version("1.1.0")`.
You may also need to add this as a repository: `maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")`